# The meaning of total derivative is zero.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, wave-equation

For function $\rho(x(t),t)$ total derivative is
$$\frac{d\rho}{dt}=\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}+\frac{d x}{d t}\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial x}$$

I'm wondering the exact meaning of following statement:

The total derivative notation should be sufficient to indicate when x and $\rho$ are being treated as functions of t on a certain curve.
$\frac{d\rho}{d t}=0$ means $\rho$ remains constant on a curve. why?

Comment: The "total derivative" says that if $\rho$ is a function of $(x,y)$ and $g(t) = \rho(x(t),t)$ then $g'(t) = x'(t)\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial x }(x(t),t)+\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial y}(x(t),t)$. The meaning is $g'(t) = 0$ where $g$ is the value of $\rho$ on the curve $(x(t),t)$. If $\forall t, g'(t) = 0$ then $g$ is constant.

Comment: I don't know why y is appeared, the meaning of total derivative is explained in Wikipedia. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative

Comment: $y$ is the name I chose for the second input variable of $\rho$

Comment: I think it is reasonable to think $y(t)=t$. $\frac{d\rho}{dt}=\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}$

Comment: sure $g(t) = \rho(x(t),y(t))$ with $y(t) = t$

Comment: Do you see why my comments answer your question ?

Comment: Yes, thank you, your comment was very helpful!

Comment: Here $\frac{d\rho}{dt}=\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}$ is not correct as $\rho$ is a function of 2 variables, not 3. Also the notation is confusing. The LHS should be $g'(t)$

Comment: Then $\frac{dg(t)}{dt}=\frac{d\rho(x,y)}{dt}=x'(t)\rho_x+\rho_y$ is correct notation?

Comment: $\frac{dg(t)}{dt}=\frac{d\rho(x(t),y(t))}{dt}=x'(t)\rho_x+\rho_y$ where implicitly $\rho_x = \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial x}(x(t),y(t))$. The notation in my 1st comment is more explicit.

Comment: Thanks your comments, I got it!!